# Dynamic Elastic search query in c# NEST

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

Started working on NEST api for elastic search recently, got stuck on following query, the data.e would be dynamically populated using the input from client in the HttpGet,
ex: user sends eventA,eventB,eventC then we would add in the should part:

```
GET events/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": 1604684158527,
            "lte": 1604684958731
            }
        }},
        {"nested": {
          "path": "data",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {"match": {
                   "data.e": "eventA"
                }},
                {"match": {
                  "data.e": "eventB"
                }},
                {"match": {
                   "data.e": "eventC"
                }},
              ]
            }
            },
          "inner_hits": {} 
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Following is what I came up with till now:

```
var graphDataSearch = _esClient.Search<Events>(s => s
                .Source(src => src
                    .Includes(i => i
                        .Field("timestamp")
                        )
                 )
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m => m
                                .Range(r => r
                                    .Field("timestamp")
                                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(startTime)
                                    .LessThanOrEquals(stopTime)
                                    ),
                                m => m
                                .Nested(n => n
                                    .Path("data")
                                    .Query(q => q
                                        .Bool(bo => bo
                                            .Should(
                                            // what to add here?
                                    )
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                    )
                ));
```

Can someone please help how to build the `should` part dynamically based on what input the user sends?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the nested query in the above snippet as shown below

```
// You may modify the parameters of this method as per your needs to reflect user input
// Field can be hardcoded as shown here or can be fetched from Event type as below
// m.Field(f => f.Data.e)

public static QueryContainer Blah(params string[] param)
{
    return new QueryContainerDescriptor<Events>().Bool(
        b => b.Should(
            s => s.Match(m => m.Field("field1").Query(param[0])),
            s => s.Match(m => m.Field("field2").Query(param[1])),
            s => s.Match(m => m.Field("field3").Query(param[2]))));
}
```

What we are essentially doing here is we are returning a `QueryContainer` object that will be passed to the nested query

```
.Query(q => Blah(<your parameters>))
```

The same can be done by adding this inline without a separate method. You may choose which ever route you perfer. However, in general, having a method of its own increases the readability and keeps things cleaner.

You can read more about `Match` usage [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/match-usage.html)

Edit:

Since you want to dynamically add the match queries inside this, below is a way you can do it.

```
private static QueryContainer[] InnerBlah(string field, string[] param)
{
    QueryContainer orQuery = null;
    List<QueryContainer> queryContainerList = new List<QueryContainer>();
    foreach (var item in param)
    {
        orQuery = new MatchQuery() {Field = field, Query = item};
        queryContainerList.Add(orQuery);
    }
    return queryContainerList.ToArray();
}
```

Now, call this method from inside of the above method as shown below

```
public static QueryContainer Blah(params string[] param)
{
    return new QueryContainerDescriptor<Events>().Bool(
        b => b.Should(
            InnerBlah("field", param)));
}
```

Comment: The part inside the should(), needs to be dynamically created, user could send 4 events or 5 events, so we have to match those too, the solution you posted is hardcoded for 3 type of params only which I showed as example.

Comment: You can loop over the items that are sent across and generate the inner match query inside of `should`. Will edit the answer to provide pointers on how to do it

Comment: @Ghanendra - Added the dynamic generation logic for multiple match queries

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to modify your code a bit to the following         `private QueryContainer[] InnerBlah(string field, List<string> param)
        {
            QueryContainer orQuery = null;
            List<QueryContainer> lq = new List<QueryContainer>();
            foreach (string item in param)
            {
                orQuery = new MatchQuery() { Field = field, Query = item };
                lq.Add(orQuery);
            }
            return lq.ToArray();
        }` , Otherwise it was creating multiple should[bool( elements in the Request json

Comment: Please update your answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Ghanendra - Ah! True that. I have amended the answer to reflect the change. Cheers!